# How can i open a model in Oracle Data Modeler without the .dmd file

Tags: oracle, oracle-sql-data-modeler

i'm using oracle data modeler for creating a logical model, today, i wasn't able to found my dmd file, but I saw a folder with the same name, inside this folder there are other folders, like businessinfo, datatypes, files, logical, etc. inside the logical folder I was able to found .xml files that represent my entities, but I don't know how to open and be able to see my model in Oracle Data Modeler

I tried looking for the dmd file but i don't see it, i only was able to found what seems to like an old version of the file, but when i clicked on the option Show in the Logical model it showed nothing